# phonegap/cordova getPicture from photolibrary file-transfer not working

Tags: cordova, upload, file-transfer, getpicture

I experience some problem in combining Cordova's camera.getPicture plugin and their FileTransfer.upload plugin. The weirdest thing is that everything works well when I take the picture from camera, and not when I retrieve it from library.

The issue looks like this one: [Phonegap/Cordova Uploading Image from gallery is not working on Android Kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021860/phonegap-cordova-uploading-image-from-gallery-is-not-working-on-android-kitkat)

But I'm using Cordova 3, so that must fix kitkat issues.

My code:

```
var imageUploadUrl = setting_api_url + "Umbraco/Api/ImageApi/PostUpload";
var formSubmitUrl = setting_api_url + "Umbraco/Api/FormApi/PostSend";
var imageUriStorage = [];
var resultsCollection = [];
var FieldId;

var take_photo = function(fieldId) {
FieldId = fieldId;
navigator.camera.getPicture(onTakeSuccess, 
                            onTakeFail, 
                            { 
    quality: 30, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    targetWidth: 800,
    targetHeight: 800,
    correctOrientation: true
});
};

var get_photo = function(fieldId) {
FieldId = fieldId;
navigator.camera.getPicture(onTakeSuccess, onTakeFail, { 
    quality: 30, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    targetWidth: 800,
    targetHeight: 800,
    correctOrientation: true });
};

var onTakeSuccess = function(imageURI) {
console.log("onTakeSuccess imageURI= " + imageURI);

var image = document.getElementById("preview-" + FieldId);

// UPLOAD PART COPIED
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var filetype = src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
if(filetype == "png") {
    options.mimeType = "image/png";
}
else if (filetype == "jpg") {
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
}

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(imageUploadUrl), image_upload_win, image_upload_fail, options);
// END.


imageUriStorage.push({ 'Id':FieldId, 'Path': imageURI});

image.src = imageURI;
};

var onTakeFail = function(message) {
alert('on take fail. Code: ' + message);
};

// called when upload succeeds        
var image_upload_win = function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
};

// when upload fails
var image_upload_fail = function (error) {
    alert("Code = " + error.code + "-" + error.http_status + ", image:" + error.source);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
};
```

Both take_photo and get_photo hit the same function onTakeSuccess, so they will get the same process. When the source is the Camera, the image is uploaded correctly and the server gives a correct response (and HTTP 201).

But, when the source is the library, this fails. The FileTransfer.Upload gives error code 1 (File not found), but this can't be true, because the image is displayed correctly in my app's image element.

The server gives HTTP 400 bad request.

**There is one difference in the process, being the format of the image's URL, but how should that make such difference?**

Log successful getPicture (CAMERA):

```
onTakeSuccess imageURI=file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.XXX.YYY/cache/1404910577158.jpg
Code = 201
Response = "8999"
Sent = 195
```

Log unsuccessful getPicture (LIBRARY):

```
onTakeSuccess imageURI= file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.XXX.YYY/cache/modified.jpg?1404910903858
upload error source file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.XXX.YYY/cache/modified.jpg?1404910903858
upload error target https://CORRECTURL/Umbraco/Api/ImageApi/PostUpload
```

Besides, the getPicture (LIBRARY) situation gives this alert:

`Code = 1-400, image:file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.XXX.YYY/cache/modified.jpg?1404910903858`

Comment: You have any solution for this? Im having the same problem, the path from my image gallery is different from imageURI

Comment: Haven't found it yet.

Comment: Probably this answer might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154810/how-to-get-image-object-using-cordova

Comment: If you are finding this now its worth noting this has been fixed in the latest release of cordova-plugin-camera. If you still have this issue make sure to update your plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current workaround is to remove the "?" and everything that follows from the imageUri. So that the URI always looks like:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.XXX.YYY/cache/modified.jpg
```

In my case this works properly and transfers the file correctly

Comment: If i remove after ? and pass modified.jpg, then also it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Using cordova 6.0.0, cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.0, cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1

I had similar problem (although probably for different reason since it's a newer version).

I found that I need to have the following lines in the config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="content:///*" />
```

NOTE: having only

```
<access origin="*" />
```

was not enough

Answer (score 0):

Yes! some files from gallery are this format:
modified.jpg?1438896451328 in name of file.

To prevent, i put some code in my upload.php file:

```
        $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $file_extension = end($temporary);

   // cortamos caracteres extraños por si llega algun nombre de archivo raro
        $cadena = $file_extension; 
        $patron = "?"; 
   // localicamos en que posición se haya "?"
        $posicion = strpos ($cadena, $patron); 
   // eliminamos los caracteres desde ? hacia la derecha
        if ($posicion !== false){
        $file_extension = substr ($cadena, 0, $posicion); 
        }
```

then you can operate for filter file type, size etc and finally save it.